# Cucumber step definitions are not being located when running from the command line

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

Been following along the cucumber book for Java and this example I am working on is very similar to what was in chapter 2. This is on the cmd line as I am not wanting to incorporate in IDE at this point.

```
Feature: practice test
  Scenario Outline: not CheckingOut bananas
    given abc
    when place holder2
    then place holder3
```

The test steps:

```
public class SimpleTest {
    @Given("^abc")
    public void part1() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("part 1");
        throw new Exception("an exceptoin");
    }

    @When("place holder2")
    public void part2(){
        System.out.println("part 2");
    }

    @Then("place holder3")
    public void part3() {
        System.out.println("part 3");
    }

}
```

I've tried the "abc", "^abc", "give abc"... on the @Given

I am driving this with the following bat file and the step definitions do compile and the class file is there. I realize on the -g (glue) option that the package name is the argument value so I made this as simple as possible 
but I am getting 0 scenarios found. The bat file is simple:

```
echo cucumber compile and execution
javac -cp "lib/*" step_definitions/SimpleTest.java 
javac -cp "lib/*;web/WEB-INF/lib/*" test/java/xxxxx/zzzz/referral/out/batch/RunCukesTest.java 
java -cp "lib/*;web/WEB-INF/lib/*;.;test/java/*" cucumber.api.cli.Main -p pretty -g step_definitions features
```

consistently I get the following results:

```
Feature: practice test

  Scenario Outline: not CheckingOut bananas ←[90m# bogus.feature:2←[0m
    given abc
    when place holder2
    then place holder3


0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.000s
```

Clearly the CLI is finding the feature file but the compiled step definitions are not being found. Doubt it is a class path issue. I've provided extra dirs and have moved the step definition file around. the CLI is not taking the feature file and matching it to the compiled definitions. Thanks ahead of time. A lot of times typing out these questions the solution is realized but on this it is not.

If the *.feature files are a requirement for cucumber to run and that they must correspond to a compiled step definition even if junit is hooks into the cucumber.class test runnner, the book could have left less room uncertainty. 
The forum for the book looked thin. Probably need to go to github or wherever the source code is.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Keep the first letter of keywords as capital ex. Given, And etc.

Secondly, Steps defined under Scenario Outline executes only and only when there are few records present in the 'Example'. Moreover, These steps will be executed 'n' number of times for 'n' records.

It can be considered as an implicit loop provided by Feature file.

Answer (score 0):

Try capitalising the first letters of Given, When, Then, And & But

Cucumber allows text before each scenario and feature, as to allow more description of what is going to happen in each. Using capital letters for the Given, When, Then, And & But, is the standard that they keep to, to know there is a step there.

So for your example:

```
Feature: practice test

Scenario: not CheckingOut bananas ←[90m# bogus.feature:2←[0m
 Given abc
 When place holder2
 Then place holder3
```

**EDIT**

Don't use the Scenario Outline syntax unless you are going to provide examples below, as demonstrated here:

```
Feature: practice test

Scenario Outline: not CheckingOut bananas ←[90m# bogus.feature:2←[0m
 Given abc
 When place holder<placeholder>
 Then place holder<placeholder2>

 Examples:
|placeholder|placeholder2|
| 1         | 2          |
| 2         | 3          |
| 3         | 4          |
```

Comment: Kyle, thanks for the help. The caps definitely were a problem so thanks. Also, I've have in there 'Outline'. I don't know exactly what that does but after removing it the CLI is behaving a lot differently. What was 'Outline' doing to me? Wonder why I got voted down.

Comment: It would have tried to find the Examples table at the bottom of the Scenario, not found it and would have thrown a fit about something it expects to be there. 

Scenario Outlines require placeholders (marked with the <> brackets) within the Scenario and an examples table with the placeholders as the headers.